# Binding values based in dropdown

Tags: html, angularjs

I have to fetch countries in a dropdown based on user id. I have tried below code but it's not working. Can someone help me out?

**HTML:**

```
<h1 align="center">Audit</h1>
<p>Country* :</p> 
<select class="form-control flat-control-inner" id=""  ng-model="user.id">
  <option value = "" > --Please Select-- </option>
  <option data-ng-repeat="c in countryList" ng-value="{{c.id}}" ng-selected="user.id==c.id">{{c.country}}</option>
</select>
```

**controller:**

```
var user={};
    $scope.user.id=1;
    $scope.userId=1;
    $scope.rgId=1;
    $scope.ctryId=1;
    $scope.trId=1;
    $scope.ctyId=1;

    $scope.fetchCountryList = function(userId){

          $(".loader").show();           
          AuditorInfoService.fetchCountryList($scope.userId).then(function(response){
               $scope.countryList = response.data;
              console.log($scope.countryList);

        },function(response){
            $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
            });        
      };
      $scope.fetchCountryList($scope.userId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish the thing you want in two ways:

1. changing the `data-ng-repeat` in `ng-repeat`
2. use `ng-options`. It is an Angular directive made especially for `select`

   `<select class="form-control flat-control-inner" ng-options="c in countryList" ng-selected="user.id==c.id" ng-model="user.id"></select>`

Docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)